# vector out of range, assigning values to an empty vector->not possible?

Tags: c++

I am quite new to c++ and am having some trouble with my program.The overall aim of the program is to find cyclic edges in a graph (in this case a molecule, which is represented as a graph). I defined the following struct in my header file:

```
typedef struct{
   std::vector<unsigned int> discovery;
   std::vector<unsigned int> lowpoints;
   std::vector<short int> cyclic;
}Cyclic;
```

In my cpp file I have this function:

```
 Cyclic Naomini::dfs_cyclic_and_acyclic_atoms(MoleculePtr mol){

   Cyclic inf_vecs;
   bool flag=false;
   AtomPtr parent;

   for(AtomPtr atom: mol->getAtoms()){
     std::cout<<"hello";                     // gets printed out
     if(!atomIsHydrogen(atom)){
     std::cout<<atom->getID();                // prints out 0
     inf_vecs.discovery.at(atom->getID())=0;  // the problem is here
     std::cout<<"hello2";                     // does not get printed out
     .
     .
     .
```

So I'm declaring a new object of type Cyclic (don't know if object is the right word here) and I am trying to access one of its vectors and assign a value to a certain position in the vector. The first position I am trying to assign a value to is position 0 (as atom->getID() returns 0). However, the compiler tells me: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what(): vector::_M_range_check"

I don't see why I can't assign a value here, is it because the vector does not contain any elements yet?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Did you ever resize your vector `inf_vecs` beyond `atom->getID()`'s value? You need to do this, because `std::vector` doesn't allow you to insert values at arbitrary positions. It's a good idea to read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) before starting to program stuff based on trial and error.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! I just solved the problem by using push_back. I guess I am really lacking some fundamental knowledge which I should catch up on...

Comment: That's why I linked you up with the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see why I can't assign a value here, is it because the vector does not contain any elements yet?

That's exactly your problem. The vector is empty, and doesn't contain any elements yet. So you can't assign any particular element in your vector with a value.

You have a misconception how [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) actually works. You can't create arbitrary positions there using the `operator[]()` or `at()` functions, these need to be there already when those functions are called.